# blind convex hull code in java

Tags: java, math, computational-geometry, convex-hull

Hi
I know that blind [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) has o(n^4)
but I have never seen its code! Is there any site that has its code?
thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you're talking about.  Google search on "blind convex hull" (in quotes) returns no hits.

Comment: it is the basic way for convex hull!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Comment: @McWafflestix, I get one hit now - from SO! :)

Comment: I think the term you're searching for is a "naïve" or "brute force" algorithm for determining the convex hull of a collection of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source code to this applet is linked from the "application notes" link.

http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lambert/java/3d/hull.html

Note: I cannot vouch for the quality of the code.